# How to value format from api in react data grid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I have my data grid in render and this.state.rows and this.state.columns
I want to change one of the columns' value from another api.

This is where getting the value of column and it is working.

```
const DataFormatter = ({ value }) => { <span>{value}</span> });
```

I want to change the value of column from an id to the name.
Here is the data object look like:

```
const data = {
    value: 3242;
    name: somename;
}
```

My new DataFormatter logs the name but doesn't render anything. It may return as an array is needed for object children. or object promise issue.

```
const DataFormatter = ({ value }) => { 

    const newValue = fetch("domain.name/{value}")
        .then(response=> response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data.name)
            return <span>data.name</span>
        });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where are you using `DateFromatter` but you are probably returning him in render of some other component.

With that in mind, you can't wait a fetch request to finish before return the value, so what you need to do is write the `DateFormatter` as a class, return null while you data is not fetched yet and do your fetch request in `componentDidMount`.

Something like that

```
class DateFormatter extends React.Component {
  constructor () {
    this.state = {
      name: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    fetch("domain.name/{this.props.value}")
      .then(response=> response.json())
      .then(data => {
          console.log(data.name)
          this.setState({name: data.name});
      });
  }

  render () {
    return <span>{this.state.name}</span>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In My case, we need to format the country code in Capes letter for that I did in the following way

```
const DataFormatter = ({ value }) => { return <span style={{textTransform: 'uppercase'}}>{value}</span> };

const columns = [
  { key: "countryCode", name: "Country", editable: false, width:75,formatter:DataFormatter }
];
```